# Data seem not to update when refreshing the page in python bottle?

Tags: python, refresh, bottle

I'm running a script that shows up some data in python bottle, one of it is signal strength that I'd like to show in real time. When I refresh the page the value doesn't change so I have to rerun the server in order to update that signal strength. I've tried ajax but it seems that it doesn't work.
What should I use to make this to work?

EDIT: The variables are lists that come from another file.

```
iplist = [192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2]
hostlist = [android234567, android677896]
maclist = [a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6, a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6]
signallist = [-56, 23]
```

.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    info={'iplist': iplist, 'maclist': maclist, 'signallist': signallist, 'hostlist': hostlist}
    tpl = '''
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ajax(){
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('signallist').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                    }
                }
                req.open('REQUEST', '../connectedDevices.py', true);
                req.send();
            }
            (function(){ajax();}, 1000);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="ajax();">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>IP address</td>
                <td>Hostname</td>
                <td>MAC address</td>
                <td>Signal</td>
            </tr>
            %for i in range(len(maclist)):
                <tr>
                    <td>{{iplist[i]}}</td>
                    <td>{{hostlist[i]}}</td>
                    <td>{{maclist[i]}}</td>
                    <td id="signallist">{{signallist[i]}}</td>
                </tr>
            %end
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    '''
    return template(tpl, info)
```

This prints a chart where it shows Ip, host, mac and signal which the one that I want to get updated in real time.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. **edit** OK I see you added a description in between. That is rather disturbing to the reader.

Comment: You have not shown where the variables for the dictionary come from.

Comment: @KlausD. I added the data I want to print, the problem I have is that I need to reload the bottle server to see the changes.

Comment: It looks like your data, which BTW is not valid Python, is loaded only on startup. It you want to reload it, you will have to do that periodically or at the beginning of the request. I can't say how since you did not show how it is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Bottle caches the templates.  So if you are feeding values in during the template creation, it will cache those values.

```
from bottle import TEMPLATES
TEMPLATES.clear()
```

Will reset those.

However, you really should think about where your data is coming and leverage websockets.  `gevent` has a great websocket library and works great with `bottle` to make your code async.   With a little work and javascript you can query your api and feed data real time into your code.

Comment: No, the problem is not related to template caching. And no, you don't need gevent, websockets or async code to solve this.

Comment: I never said need.  Websockets makes updating the page easy and efficient, so it WOULD solve the problem.

Comment: Websockets are also the correct tool for real time updating of web content.  Can you explain why this is not the case?

Comment: With a websocket you can push data that exist on the server to the client. The question is about updating the data on the server. That is one step earlier.

Comment: That is wrong.  He wants his page to reflect the change FROM the source.  When the source changes, it should push to the client. His problem is that his AJAX is not updating the values, that is being handled by the template.

Comment: Klaus you are obviously not interested in an answer, and just trolling.  The question is how does he get his website to update with a value coming from a device in real time.  The file is changing, but not updating the webclient.  Websockets would be the perfect solution for updating the web page, and he needs an async process to poll the file/device to provide real time updates.

Comment: No, he is loading the files once into a module namespace. The loaded data does not change then until he reloads the server. So, you have not understood what the question is about.

Comment: Klaus.... He wants the website to reflect changes in the file/source.  He wants real time updates to the website, which is why he is refreshing the page. The file is changing, which is why the website changes once he reloads. Why am I arguing with you... The OP needs to weigh in here.